# UPS free shipping & discounted shipping in PHP

Tags: php, ups

I implement general UPS shipping but now client ask to implement free,discounted & flat shipping.I found forums but did not get correct answer.
I want to generate **shipping label** for each order from shipping.
Please explain how to implement this with existing shipping module ?
what will be **flow** of this type of shipping ?
Please make me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Show what you have done so far and where do you have troubles

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/476

Comment: @Anton Actually I want ot know how to implement flat rate shipping & free shipping. Any tutorial is available for working about flat rate shippping with general UPS shipping.

Comment: What exactly is your *problem* or *question* regarding implementation of flat rate shipping?! Is the business logic unclear to you? Is there some API you don't know how to use?

Answer (score 0):

@von If you're building something from scratch, you need to code for the UPS APIs to rate and ship. If you've got some cart template, look for a UPS rating module before you attempt to write your own. Sorry, you didn't provide enough info in your original question to give a more in-depth answer.